# Storing AWS IAM keys

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-rds, amazon-iam

I need to assign for every user of my platforme an `AWS IAM` identity. Is it safe to store `AWS IAM` identities in my `RDS` ?

Comment: You should use AWS Secrets. Link: https://aws.amazon.com/secrets-manager/

Answer (score 1):

'safe' is a relative term, but I don't think anyone would recommend storing passwords in your database.

Its relatively safe to store the IAM id in RDS, but not the secret key/password. If someone gets in, they now have access to all of your accounts.

There is a reason that AWS only shows you the secret key/password once, and doesn't let you see it again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there a solution that you can  recommend me.

Comment: why do you need to store them at all? You should give out the keys to the users and if they forget/lose them, you can reset the secret key. Even better, have a policy where the keys get rotated on a regular basis so that even keys in the wrong hands don't last long.

Comment: I need them to be stored because until now all users use the same credentials to upload files to s3 bucket using ruby sdk for aws. the users will use the credentials but should not  have it.

Comment: @AnassAnas `the users will use the credentials but should not have it.` ?? you mean you want to have an application which stores the content "on behalf of a user"?

Comment: @gusto yes that's it